# Displaying based on classes in children in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

```
<div className="optimise-page">
<Row>
    <Col sm={7} >
        <div className="optimise-panel">
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    </Col>

    <Col sm={5}>
        <div className="preview-panel">
            <JobPostingControl jobDescription={jobPosting.data} isLoading={search.previewRequestState.isBusy || previewByTemplate.isBusy} />
        </div>
    </Col>
</Row>
```

My JobPostingControl component has to display a screen based on the className's inside the `{this.props.children}` which is of type `React.ReactNode`. What is the best way to go about doing this? preferably within JobPostingControl

Comment: Can't you pass class name as a state to both the `className` and as a prop to `JobPostingControl` ?

Comment: The problem I am having is getting the classNames from {this.props.children} because its type (React.ReactNode) is difficult to work with for me

Answer (score 1):

First off, you may want to rethink your app's organization.

If you can't get around this, you can render your children via something like the following:

```
private renderChildrenByClassName(): JSX.Element[] {
    return React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child) => {
        return this.renderChildByClassName((child as React.ReactElement<any>).props.className);
    }
}
```

where `renderChildByClassName` is some function that takes a space-delimited list of class names and spits out `JSX.Element`. Note that the cast is required here because `ReactNode` can be `ReactElement` or `ReactText`. Also be extra careful about what you actually pass to your `JobPostingControl` component. This function assume that the children as always `ReactElement` and that they always have a `className` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure, I'm not very experienced with React.

To further my comment, I would try to use the class as a state in the parent component and pass it as a prop to the `JobPostingControl` component.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      className: 'foo'
    };
  }

  render () {
    return (
     <div className={this.state.className}>
      <JobPostingControl setPropName={this.state.className} />
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```